# SMTP: In which order which "from" email address would be used?

Tags: smtp, email-headers

I'm currently coding from scratch a new SMTP server and I'm asking in which order "from" address counts?

If I receive an email with the following content:

```
Return-Path: foo1@bar.tld
...
From: Foo Bar <foo2@bar.tld>
```

and the email was received by the SMTP server with the command:

```
MAIL FROM: foo3@bar.tld
```

And my server wants now to answer on this email, on which address should it answer?
I guess the order would be first of the email header the `"From:"` address, then `"Return-Path:"`, and if all this would be missing, then the address of the `"MAIL FROM"` command of the SMTP command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Return-Path` is used for sending bounce messages (i.e. delivery status notifications), replies should be sent to `Reply-to` if it exists, otherwise `From`.

Note that when the mail is received with

```
MAIL FROM: <foo3@bar.tld>
```

the `Return-Path` header should be updated to contain that address.

Comment: And if email content is empty (if you sent a dot just after the DATA SMTP command)?

Comment: `From` is a required header. Some servers might synthesize a missing `From` header using `Return-Path`, but that's not required.

Comment: I guess a missing `To` header entry will be on some server synthesized from the SMTP command `RCPT TO`?

Comment: Not usually. `To` is not a required header; if there's no To or CC, everyone is a BCC.